# Overshoot when plotting fast oscillating function with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

When plotting fast oscillating data from a table with pgfplots, an overshoot of the curve was observed (due to interpolation?). If the same data was plotted using Matlab, no overshoot occurred. The same phenomenon was observed when plotting a fast oscillating function, instead of data from a table. Here is the minimum working example, where a chirp signal `sin(x^2)` is displayed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=150,ymin=-1.2,ymax=1.2,width=0.4\textwidth,height=0.3\textwidth]
    \addplot[
        thick,
        mark=none,
        domain=0:150,
        samples=1000,
    ] {sin(x^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The figure was compiled using PDFLaTeX, from the MiKTeX distribution. One can note that the curve overshoots 1 in absolute value, starting around the abscissa x=50. How to remove these spurious peaks?

Comment: They are called miters. They get longer for acute angles.

Comment: Add this after `\usepackage{pgfplots}`: `\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={line join=round, line cap=round}}`